# PHP Query Generator/Reporter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, search

I'm in the process of tweaking a web application and so far I've had some really helpful guys from here, explaining things in layman's terms. Thank you.

One of the abilities I wanted in my app was the ability to search through records and use the result to generate different kinds of useful reports. In my workplace we use a system like the image below to do just this.

[Report Generator](http://www.arongalabuzi.co.uk/stuff/query/app.png)

Aside from searching and generating reports, I will need the ability to save a user's search criteria for easy retrieval of future searches.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The image you linked looks a lot like something I have wished for many times. I have thought about diving in and writing my own app but never had a good enough reason to.

I did a bit of searching and discovered that there isn't a lot out there.

This one http://mysql-reports.com/ is pretty basic but would work for someone generating custom SQL statements or for someone that isn't capable of writing their own SQL queries.

I wish I had more ideas! Hopefully someone else will.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but it might be a start.

[PM Report](http://www.busmgtsys.com/downloads.php)

I've used it with some modification in the past and it has worked well for me.  It may not be the prettiest thing in the world but it's a start.